# How to implement Yii CActiveDataProvider parse complex expression?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to implement something similar to the way Yii CActiveDataProvider parse complex expressions. Take the following codes as an example, I would basically like to be able to specify something like 'date("M j, Y", $data->create_time)' in the value.

Any one knows which class in Yii will provide good insight? I looked at CDataColumn class, but not much luck.

```
$this-widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=$dataProvider,
'columns'=array(
    'title',          // display the 'title' attribute
    'category.name',  // display the 'name' attribute of the 'category' relation
    'content:html',   // display the 'content' attribute as purified HTML
    array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
        'name'='create_time',
        'value'='date("M j, Y", $data-create_time)',
    ),
),
```

));

Comment: Looks like the answer maybe in here? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent#evaluateExpression-detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to create a widget that can evaluate a PHP Expression?

There is this method [`evaluateExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent#evaluateExpression-detail) which is also used by CDataColumn. You can see how the CDataColumn use it in the method [`renderDataCellContent`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CDataColumn.php#L129).

As you see the code inside method [`evaluateExpression`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/base/CComponent.php#L602), it is using [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) and [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

And if you use PHP 5.3, you can use anonymous function for this. e.g.

```
$this-widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' = $dataProvider,
    'columns' = array(
        'title',          // display the 'title' attribute
        'category.name',  // display the 'name' attribute of the 'category' relation
        'content:html',   // display the 'content' attribute as purified HTML
        array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
            'name' => 'create_time',
            'value' => function($data){
                return date("M j, Y", $data->create_time);
            }
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Thanks Petra for the response. Basically, I would like to create my own evaluation